# Strategy for handling variable time queries?

Tags: asp.net, sql, performance, caching, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a typical scenario that I'm struggling with from a performance standpoint.  The user selects a value from a dropdown and clicks a button. A stored procedure takes that value as an input parameter, executes, and returns the results to a grid.  For just one of the values ('All'), the query runs for roughly 2.5 minutes.  For the rest of the values the query runs less than 1ms.

Obviously, having the user wait for 2.5 minutes just isn't going to fly.  So, what are some typical strategies to handle this?

Some of my own thoughts:

- New table that stores the information for the 'All' value and is generated nightly
- Cache the data on the caching server

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

**Update**

A little bit more info:

sp returns two result sets.  The first is a group by rollup summary and the second is the first result set, disaggregated (roughly 80,000 rows).

Comment: You will get better assistance if you can show us your query and table structure

Comment: 2.5 minutes is very long. So unless it's really a lot of data, there might be issues with your query or indexes, hence it would be good to have some more info, as Abe Miessler already suggested.

Comment: @Abe My sp contains complex business and domain logic.  I don't think it will help to paste that here.  I had worded my question in a very general way, I'm looking for a general answer.

Comment: Do you think that 80k rows will be useful to a user?

Comment: 80k is A LOT of records, but I would say that depends on the business logic and exactly what it is needed for... considering that it would probably take most users 2 minutes to just get through a 1k records considering they KNOW what they are looking for... im thinking ajax might be your best bet.

Comment: @Abe That's a great point. Personally? No, I don't think it will be useful.  The grid is using paging, but still.  What my boss thinks, that's another story.

Comment: Bleh, bosses drive me nuts some times....

Comment: +1 for bosses and crazy requirements

Comment: can you do the summary and the result set seperately? if your doing BOTH in the sp it and it takes 1 minute to do the summary and 1.5 minute to do the results, etc... again w/o knowing exactly, its really hard to fathom.

Comment: @Patrick - I'm looking at that possibility now.  Currently, both result sets are queried from the same @temp table

Comment: @Patrick - Separating won't matter.  99 % of the time is spent in the populating the temp table that both share, not the actual queries that return the result sets

Comment: then it sounds like you might HAVE to do some form of caching or another... how often does this data change?  if it changes often and the users expect realtime results that I think your getting to the land of "you may want it but you ain't getting it" (customers hate that but what can you do... sometimes THAT is the case)  otherwise something like a nightly "timeslice" might be a blessing in disguise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caching data is a good thing, but.... if the SP is inherently flawed, then you might want to actually fix it instead of trying to bandage it with caching.

You might also want to (since you didn't mention here) look at the number of rows "All" returns compared to the other selections and think about your indexes.

Also in your SP does the "All" cause it to run a different sets of tsql as in maybe a case or an if... or is it running the same code just with a different "WHERE"?

It might simply be that "ALL" just returns A LOT of records.  You may want to implement paging and partial dataset return using ajax... (kinda like return the first 1000 records early so that it can be displayed and also show a throbber on the screen while the rest of the dataset is returned)

These are all options... if the number of records really isnt that different between ALL and the others... then it probably has something to do with the query/index/program flow.

Comment: The sp is not flawed, it's just a lot of data.

Comment: like I said if its returning THAT much data caching or async returns are your best bet.  To many people depend on caching with bad queries... if you are confident in your SP, and your returning that many rows then there are other options.

Comment: To your second point: Regardless of the parameter the code is the same (a single code path), isnull is wrapped around the parameter and when 'All' is passed it essentially sets the param to null.

Comment: are there inner joins that include nulls? because THAT will bog down just about any query.

Comment: @Patrick - Not sure I follow.  None of the join criteria will contain nulls ( the fields that make up the join both left and right side never have null )

Comment: Ya, so basically what google does with their search results?  The thing is I still need that summary result set and it cannot be based on just 1000 rows.

Comment: like if the left table of the join has a value in a field and its joined counter part in the right table does not exist... it will return "null" then if you try to join THAT to another table it builds another null... so you'll have a row with mostly nulls based on non existant records as a part of a join.

Comment: i cant say for sure about google... you can do a search and get something like: About 439,000,000 results (0.16 seconds) which may or may not be async/legit... but consider the computing power that google uses for these searches plus the ammount of caching ability they have as well...

Answer (score 2):

I would first look at if your have the proper indexes in place.  Using the Query Analyzer and the Database Tuning Assistant is a simple and often effective way of seeing what indexes might help.

If you still have performance problems after creating the appropriate indexes you might then look at adding tables/views to speed things up.  If your query does a lot of joins you might consider creating an indexed view that allows you to do a select with no joins on the denormalized data.  Since indexed views are persisted you can see big gains from their use.

You can read up on indexed views here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd171921%28v=sql.100%29.aspx

and read about the database tuning adviser here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166575.aspx

Also, how many records does "All" return?  I have seen people get hung up on the "All" scenario before, but if it returns 1 million records or something then the data is not usable to a person anyways...